# Which whitespaces in a pretty printed HTML code can be ignored?

Tags: python, html

We convert HTML based documents into book form. The input HTML often consists of many line breaks and indented lines so that it is human readable in a normal text editor. Such indented lines mostly consists of whitespaces. A browser normally ignores these whitespaces. For example:

```
    <p>
        This is a text with two lines<br>
        and this is the second line.
    </p>
```

When rendering this in a browser the whitespaces in front of the two lines and the line break after 
 are completely ignored and the text appears as if the HTML code would look like this:

```
<p>This is a text with two lines<br>and this is the second line.</p>
```

I need a function in python that can parse the first HTML code and outputs the second HTML code without the "pretty print" whitespaces. The best solution would also create XHTML so it can be parsed with ElementTree.

I heard BeautifulSoup can do such things but it seem not to work as expected. Here are some examples:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
input = """    <p>
        This is a text with two lines<br>
        and this is the second line.
    </p>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(input, 'html.parser')
print unicode(soup)
```

This will print the following string:

```
u' <p>\n        This is a text with two lines<br/>\n        and this is the second line.\n    </p>'
```

As you can see there is a space before the `<p>` and also the line breaks and spaces are still there. You get a similar output using the `lxml` parser:

```
u'<html><body><p>\n        This is a text with two lines<br/>\n        and this is the second line.\n    </p></body></html>'
```

Then there are formatters available for the `prettify` method. Using no formatter at all it results in something similar what I would expect.

```
soup.prettify(formatter = None)
```

results in this:

```
u'<p>\n This is a text with two lines\n <br>\n and this is the second line.\n</p>'
```

But there are still line breaks in there. There are also line breaks before the `<br>` now which makes no sense to me.

Even if I would iterate over all the text and replace the line breaks with nothing there would still be some whitespaces where no space should appear. Is there a better library or something I did not fin which can help me to create the following result?

```
<p>This is a text with two lines<br>and this is the second line.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have your result formated in a proper way via BeautifullSoup or Prettify or other one, you could perform a substitution using a regular expression with `re.sub()`.

```
import re

s = "<p>\n This is a text with two lines\n <br>\n and this is the second line.\n</p>"
replaced = re.sub('\n ', '', s)

print replaced
```

Comment: I can check that idea but as the input documents are relatively heavy it may happen that things get replaced which should not be replaced. But as `\n` should never be a valid character it may help identifying the whitespaces around that character.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the HTML is well-formed and that there are no < or > symbols which are not part of the document structure (such as in a comment or JavaScript block), you could use this regex substitution to replace all whitespace immediately preceeding and following all HTML tags:

```
import re

input = """    <p>
        This is a text with two lines<br>
        and this is the second line.
    </p>"""

print(re.sub(r'\s*(<.*?>)\s*', r'\1', input))
```

Comment: Removing all whitespaces around HTML tags is not the solution because sometimes they are important like in a comma separated list: `<a>this</a>, <a>that</a> and also <a>these</a>`

Comment: Good point, I didn't give enough consideration to in-line elements.

Answer (score -1):

Try this unicode code for white space.

```
&nbsp;
```

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp